# Sequential Firebase cloud function promises

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I still don't get how I could make cloud functions works sequentially.
Here is my code :

```
export const Run = functions.database.ref("PATH").onUpdate((snap, 
context) =>
{
const Collection = [];
ref.child('PATH2').once('value', function(lambda) 
{
    lambda.forEach((snap) => 
    {
        if (snap.val().state) 
        {
            Collection.push(snap.key);
        }
        return false; //since I use typescript I must return a boolean with foreach loop
    });
}).then(() => 
{
for (let i = 0; i < Collection.length; i++) 
{
    const arg = Collection[i];

        if(Verify(arg))
        {
            break;
        }

        Function_A(arg)
        .then(() => {
            return Function_B(arg)
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Function_C(arg);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Function_D(arg);
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Function_E(arg)
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Function_F(arg)
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Function_G(arg)
        })
}
})
});
```

The problem is that Function C starts before Function B has been completed. How could I make it works sequentially? I really need function B to be completely fulfilled before going to the next function.

Comment: Does every `Function_X` return a promise?

Comment: Also, you I think mean "sequentially", not "synchronously". The one thing means *"A runs before B runs before C..."*, the other means *"your program freezes completely until G has returned"*.

Comment: @Tomalak yes you are right.. I mean sequentially! I edited my post. 
Also, yes they all return a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to let a number of promises ("promise-returning asynchronous functions") run in sequence is to chain them.

```
Promise.resolve(init)
    .then(result => function1(result))    // result will be init
    .then(result => function2(result))    // result will be the result of function1
    .then(result => function3(result));   // result will be the result of function2
                                          // overall result will be that of function 3

// more succinctly, if each function takes the previous result
Promise.resolve(init).then(function1).then(function2).then(function3);
```

This pattern can be expressed generically, i.e. with a variable number of functions, using an array and a `.reduce()` call:

```
var funcs = [function1, function2, function3, functionN];
var chain = funcs.reduce((result, nextFunc) => nextFunc(result), Promise.resolve(init));
```

Here `chain` is a single promise (the last one in the chain). It will resolve when the chain has resolved.

Now, assuming that we have functions A through G, and assuming that `lambda` is an array of values:

```
const funcSequence = [Function_A, Function_B, Function_C, Function_D, Function_E, Function_F, Function_G];

const chains = lambda
    .filter(snap => snap.val().state && Verify(snap.key))
    .map(snap => funcSequence.reduce((result, func) => func(snap.key), Promise.resolve(/* init */)));
```

`chains` will be an array of promise chains (an array of *last promises of each chain*, precisely). All chains wills run in parallel, but each individual chain will run in sequence. All we need to do now is to wait for all of them to resolve.

```
Promise.all(chains).then(results => console.log(results));
```

Todo: Add error handling.

The above can also be done with loops and `async`/`await`. You can convert the code and see which approach you like better.

Comment: This answer looks awesome. But I can't figure out what is "init" ?

Comment: It's whatever you want to initialize the chain with. The argument you want to give to the first function. If you feed the same constant argument to all functions (like `snap.key` in your case) then you don't need it. If you look closely, I'm not setting it in the last code sample.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clarification. It works like a charm! I'm now able to handle a sequence!  I really misunderstood the chaining concept. I thought by just using return & .then it would chain everything but .. WRONG! You saved my day if not my month!

Comment: If you are chaining database calls against a single database here, make sure you wrap them in a transaction. You don't want to have the database in an undefined state when half of the calls succeed and there is a single error. Transaction "commit" goes into the final piece of each chain, "rollback" goes into the error handler of each promise chain.